# How to automatically create custom taxonomy from custom post type title

Tags: wordpress, post, types, taxonomy

I want to automatically create custom taxonomy items from the title of custom post type whenever a post is created. The CPT title is Hotel, and the taxonomy name is HotelCategory
Example:
 CPT Name: **Hotel LakeView** when created automatically creates a custom taxonomy item named: **Hotel LakeView**.
I have been finding the answers with no luck. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in function.php

```
add_action( 'publish_{post_type_name}', 'add_hotel_term' );

function add_hotel_term( $post_ID ) {

    $post = get_post( $post_ID ); // get post object

    wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'HotelCategory' );
}
```

Hope it help!